# Slickgrid grouping rows style

Tags: slickgrid

In this example:

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping

You can group the rows by certain columns, but I would like the rows inside the groups to be indented. Is there a way I can add a class to the grouped rows or something? I can't seem to find a good way to do this.

I'm creating the grouping by doing:

```
function groupByDuration() {
  dataView.setGrouping({
    getter: "duration",
    formatter: function (g) {
      return "Duration:  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding my own custom formatter to the first column.

```
var myFormatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    var groupings = this.getGrouping().length;
    var indentation = groupings * 15 + 'px';
    var spacer = '<span style="margin-left:' + indentation + '"></span>';
    return spacer + value;
};
```

I bind the function to slickgrid's dataView so I can access the groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(".slick-row:not(.slick-group)").css('margin-left','20px');
```

This will give you all the rows(divs) which don't have class `slick-group` i.e. who are the grouped rows.

For nested groups, you have to check whether any of the parent has class `slick-group` by `closest()` and apply the margin accordingly

Comment: Though it might be a valid solution, explaining a little bit won't harm and will help the user to understand better.