# Slickgrid Grouping Row CSS

Tags: css, slickgrid

In this example:

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping

You can group the rows by certain columns, but I would like the rows inside the groups to be indented. Is there a way I can add a class to the grouped rows or something? I can't seem to find a good way to do this.

I'm creating the grouping by doing:

```
function groupByDuration() {
  dataView.setGrouping({
    getter: "duration",
    formatter: function (g) {
      return "Duration:  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";
    }
  });
}
```

I tried this [Slickgrid grouping rows style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895328/slickgrid-grouping-rows-style)

```
var myFormatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    var groupings = this.getGrouping().length;
    var indentation = groupings * 15 + 'px';
    var spacer = '<span style="margin-left:' + indentation + '"></span>';
    return spacer + value;
};
```

But my question is How do I bind this function with slickgrid's dataView so I can access the groupings as currently I am getting the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'getGrouping'"

Thanks

Thanks!

Comment: I feel like getGrouping() is an internal function not exposed to you. Are you using an API reference for the grouping functions that I can't seem to locate ?

Comment: I am using an API reference                                          dataView.setGrouping([{
                getter: "regionalDirectorName",
                aggregateCollapsed: true,
                lazyTotalsCalculation: false
            }                                                                                                         but I am not able to getGrouping object i.e regionalDirectorName in the function hence I get this error Object doesn't support property or method 'getGroupin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are trying to shift left some of the column values or the header of the group based on the number of the grouped up rows.

I've modified the grouping-example `groupByDuration` formatter to try and show this off. Here is the [link to the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c76xW/3/).

If I haven't gotten to the root of what you are trying to accomplish, please try and update the jsFiddle further to illustrate what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank You! Additionally do you know how can we show the total avg and total cost on Duration(Expanded/collapsed) row?

Comment: I added a separate question if you would rather answer there..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140813/slickgrid-grouped-header-showtotal Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah if you have more questions I could probably just edit the answers here or there. I've already answered there though.

Comment: Thank You. I need some more help, whenever you get a chance question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277221/slickgrid-grouped-header-row Thanks