# Slickgrid Grouped header ShowTotal

Tags: css, slickgrid

How can I show the total average and total cost on Duration(Expanded/collapsed) row where number of items are instead of at the bottom in a separate row?

here is the fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/c76xW/3/

```
dataView.setGrouping([
    {
      getter: "duration",
      formatter :function (g) {
        return "Duration:  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";
      },
      aggregators: [
        new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("duration"),
        new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("cost")
      ],
      aggregateCollapsed: true,
      lazyTotalsCalculation: true
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to modify it a bit. [JSfiddle link with updated code is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/c76xW/4/)
Be careful with the `aggregateCollapsed` and `lazyTotalsCalculation` - they need to be set to true if you want to access the average and sum in that way, but it also means it will run slower since it's doing it for each and every group at the same time and not when the user is looking at them.

Comment: Thank You for your help. You are awesome. But I see the totals twice, at the bottom too. Its kind of redundant. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: Thank You Thank You Thank You... I promise this is the last question.. How do I get rid of that extra Row where we earlier had total counts?

Comment: No problem :) and I kind of knew that one was coming, but I really don't have a good solution to that one. Will have to get back to you.

Comment: That works.. I will try to solve it from my end as well. Thanks much

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c76xW/7/ there you go, turns out it's a simple option. Checkout this link https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js starting on line 53 to 65 you can see the options available.

Comment: You are a life saver. I was using displayTotalsRow : false in   var options = { displayTotalsRow : false} Thanks again for your help. I wish I had a five star rating option :)

Comment: No worries - I learned a lot as well. If you look into that file I mentioned in my last comment, it might give you a better idea on how to do the previous stuff you asked about in all the other questions. Might be the more correct way :)